# Why does aliasing a package cause Android Studio to not be able to find the same function that it could find when the package was unaliased?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, sqflite

I took this function from https://suragch.medium.com/simple-sqflite-database-example-in-flutter-e56a5aaa3f91.

**This works:**

```
  import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';

  Future<int> localDBQueryRowCount({required sqf.Database db, required String table}) async {
    final results = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table');
    return Sqflite.firstIntValue(results) ?? 0;
  }
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
  import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sqf;

  Future<int> localDBQueryRowCount({required sqf.Database db, required String table}) async {
    final results = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $table');
    return sqf.firstIntValue(results) ?? 0; //ERROR HERE ON "firstIntValue": The function 'firstIntValue' isn't defined.
  }
```

Why does aliasing a package cause Android Studio to not be able to find the same function that it could find when the package was unaliased?

Comment: Ok I figured it out but I don't understand why. I had to do `return sqf.Sqflite.firstIntValue(results) ?? 0;` while the package was aliased. But why did I have to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dart doesn't have "real" aliases. `as` just add a **prefix** to the library.

That's why `sqf.firstIntValue(results)` doesn't work. Instead, using `sqf` as a prefix, makes it work: `sqf.Sqflite.firstIntValue(results)`.

Reference: https://dart.dev/language/libraries#specifying-a-library-prefix

Answer (score 0):

If you use aliases `import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart' as sqf;` you should use this:

```
return sqf.Sqflite.firstIntValue(results) ?? 0;
```

Because you create alias `sqf` for file `sqflite.dart` and then you should to use the Sqflite class from this file. So you can do this by `sqf.Sqflite`.